# Python creating dynamic global variable from list

Tags: python, dynamic, global-variables

I am trying to make generic config, and thus config parser. There are two config files say A and B. I want to parse sections and make global values from them according to hardcoded list.

Here is an example:

in config file:

```
[section]
var1 = value1
var2 = value2
```

In global scope:

```
some_global_list = [ ["var1","var2"], ["var3","var4"] ]
```

in function to unpack this values, by ConfigParser:

```
configparser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configparser.read(some_config_filename)

for variables in some_global_list:
    globals()[section]=dict()
    for element in configparser.items(section):
        globals()[section].update({element[0]:element[1]})
```

This works nicely...*however*. Scope of globals() seem to be limited to function which is obviously not what I intended. I can access variable only while in that function.

*Could someone share better yet simple idea?* 
I know that i might move code to main and not to worry, but I don't think it is a good idea. 
I thought also about making some generator (sorry for pseudocode here):

in global scope:

```
for x in some_global_list:
    globals()[x] = x
```

also tried adding this to function:

```
for x in some_global_list[0]:
    global x
```

but got nowhere.

Edit :

After discussion below, here it is:

Problem solved like this:

1. removed whole configuration from main script to module
2. imported (from module import somefunction) config from module
3. removed globals() in fact didnt need them, since function was changed a little like so:

in function:

```
def somefunction:
#(...)

configparser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configparser.read(some_config_filename)

temp_list=[]
for variables in some_global_list:
    tmp=dict()
    for element in configparser.items(section):
    tmp.update({element[0]:element[1]})
temp_list.append (tmp)
return temp_list #this is pack for one file.
```

now in main script

```
tmp=[]
for i,conf_file in enumerate([args.conf1,args.conf2,args.conf3]):
    if conf_file:
        try:
            tmp.append([function(params...)])
        except:
            #handling here
        #but since i needed those config names as global variables 
    for j,variable_set in enumerate(known_variable_names[i]):
        globals()[variable_set] = tmp[i][j]
```

so unfortunate hack presists. But seems to work. Thx for Your help guys.

I'm accepting (if thats possible) below answer since it gave me good idea :)

Comment: Stop messing with globals and use a `dict()` to hold your sections instead? There very rarely is a need to poke in `globals()`.

Comment: I am reading that into dict() but i wanted that each section was global dict like :

var1 = dict() and 

var1 = value1

Comment: Yes, I understood what you wanted to do, I am saying you shouldn't do that, period. What if your user added a section called `configparser`  to the config file? You now let a user-controlled configuration file break your code.

Comment: So if I understand You correctly, I should just import whole config inside main, not in delegate function.

Comment: No, you should not set globals from a config file is what I am saying. You *can* set globals from a function, I am saying *you should not do that*.

Comment: OK, but then how do I use anything that's imported from config anywhere else if not by global? Passing multiple arguments doesn't seem like a good solution either.

Comment: @brainovergrow If I understand you correctly, you need a way to make your config values accessible throughout your application?

Comment: @brainovergrow: Then set *one* global for your config information `config = {}` and in your function add to that mapping. `config[section] = dict()`, etc.

Comment: Yes. But, when i set them inside function with globals()[new_variable]   it appears that globals() are local to that function (?) and outside, new_variable is not visible

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are several configuration files. Each of them have separate configuration options, and about 8 sections, not related to each other. I'd follow Your suggestion, but I'm afraid I'd got lost if went too deep

Comment: @brainovergrow: Then create separate configuration globals for them. Or nest them one level deeper. The point I am trying to make is that you should *not* use your `globals()` as the global dictionary for your configuration. All you need to do is add *one* named dictionary global that you use instead.

Comment: I think You just made me think :) Why am I not simply returning each of this dict's to caller ? I'm not insisting over using globals, I don't like this idea, but that's why I've asked, to find better solution. I'll try to use Yours as well, however not sure if i know how ( py beginner :) ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve this issue is in your application package within the `__init__.py` you can do something similar to the following:

```
app_config = read_config()

def read_config():
    configparser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    configparser.read(some_config_filename)
    return configparser.as_dict() #An imaginery method which returns the vals as dict.
```

The "app_config" variable can be imported into any other module within the application.

Comment: I will check that. Although - not sure if i can pass some_config_filename from argparse, and avoid moving all configuration steps to __init__ ;)

Comment: @brainovergrow you should consider to centralise your bootstrap code into a single module for an instance bootstrap.py.

Comment: Hm, but if i modularize this, i guess i'd need two additional files: 
\_\_init\_\_.py and bootstrap.py, am i right ?

Comment: @brainovergrow If you do have a __init__.py and if the application is small then the initialization can be done within it. But it seems that you are writing a script to run from the command line and possibly the config file path is passed as a CLI argument. Is this correct?

Comment: Config path can be passed, as an option (with argparse defaults). I'm passing it along to configreader function, so no problem here.

I've moved configreader function to module, and with handy "from somemodule import configreader" works. Same way as before, but I suppose I will be able to pass needed config back to main script.