# dynamic variables from list

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

This is similar to, [Python creating dynamic global variable from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947221/python-creating-dynamic-global-variable-from-list), but I'm still confused.

I get lots of flo data in a semi proprietary format.  I've already used Python to strip the data to my needs and save the data into a json file called `badactor.json` and are saved in the following format:

`[saddr as a integer, daddr as a integer, port, date as Julian, time as decimal number]`

An arbitrary example `[1053464536, 1232644361, 2222, 2014260, 15009]`

I want to go through my weekly/monthly flo logs and save everything by Julian date.  To start I want to go through the logs and create a list that is named according to the Julian date it happened, i.e, `2014260` and then save it to the same name `2014260.json`.  I have the following, but it is giving me an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

import calendar
#these are varibles I've had to use throughout, kinda a boiler plate for now
x=0
templist2 = []
templist3 = []
templist4 = []
templist5 = []
bad = {}
#this is my list of "bad actors", list is in the following format
#[saddr as a integer, daddr as a integer, port, date as Julian, time  as decimal number]
#or an arbitrary example [1053464536, 1232644361, 2222, 2014260, 15009]
badactor = 'badactor.json'

with open(badactor, 'r') as f1:
    badact = json.load(f1)
f1.close()

for i in badact:
    print i[3] #troubleshooting to verify my value is being read in
    tmp = str(i[3])
    print tmp#again just troubleshooting
    tl=[i[0],i[4],i[1],i[2]]
    bad[tmp]=bad[tmp]+tl
    print bad[tmp]
```

Trying to create the variable is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "savetofiles.py", line 39, in <module>
    bad[tmp]=bad[tmp]+tl
KeyError: '2014260'
```

Comment: The key referenced by `tmp` - `'2014260'` in this case - doesn't exist in `bad`.

Comment: Has bad beed defined?

Comment: Am I missing something? This doesn't seem like minimal working example because I don't see you have defined bad as a dictionary anywhere in supplied code? (I might be blind though)

Comment: If `bad` was undefined it would be a `NameError`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3; and there is if you try to run his code. He defined bad somewhere and hasn't shown it in his MWE. Issue he's having is that bad is missing a key, and we can't say why till he shows us how he added to his dict.

Comment: bad is defined just below templist5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you initialize `bad` to be an empty [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of just regular built-in `dict`. i.e.

```
import collections
  ...
bad = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

That way, initial empty `list` values will be created for you automatically the first time a date key is encountered and the error you're getting from the `bad[tmp]=bad[tmp]+tl` statement will go away since it will effectively become `bad[tmp]=list()+tl` — where the `list()` call just creates and returns an empty list — the first time a particular date is encountered.

It's also not clear whether you really need the `tmp = str(i[3])` conversion because values of any non-mutable type are valid dictionary (or `defaultdict`) keys, not just strings — assuming `i[3]` isn't a string already. Regardless, subsequent code would be more readable if you named the result something else, like `julian_date = i[3]` (or `julian_date = str(i[3])` if the conversion really is required).

Comment: The "import collections" piece was a great help!  I'm moving along now.  

Without trying to sound too needy, is there a more efficient way I should have coded?

Comment: My apologies, I tried to click the "this answer is useful", but it wouldn't let me without enough reputation. .  I assumed the check mark fell under the same rule set.

Comment: Thanks. One change you might want to consider is also replacing the `bad[tmp]=bad[tmp]+tl` with `bad[tmp].append(tl)` because that way, the value for each date key in `bad` will be a list of lists instead of one long merged list of all the items on a date. Doing so might make subsequent processing of the contents of `bad` easier.

Answer (score 2):

By the time your code is executed, there is no key "2014260" in the "bad" dict.

Your problem is here:

```
bad[tmp]=bad[tmp]+tl
```

You're saying "add t1 to something that doesn't exist."

Instead, you seem to want to do:

```
bad[tmp]=tl
```